# Cheap, small device that has wifi and touchscreen, and can run a browser

Tags: wifi, touchscreen, smart-home

I use Logitech media server, installed on a NAS, to stream music. I like using my android tablet to control the server. And I would like to always see what track is playing. But I don't like to keep the tablet's screen on in the background for long periods of time, in order to conserve the battery. I could buy another, cheap, tablet and keep it always plugged in to the mains, but I would prefer that it wouldn't have a battery (out of concerns that it might overheat or explode).

So, is there a cheap, small device with a screen and wifi, that doesn't have a battery and runs connected to the mains? Something like a mounted wall display, I guess.

Comment: Have you tried using apps that keep your Android screen alive? Such as: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.synetics.stay.alive One thing to be careful of however is damaging your screen/device as most devices (if not all) are not designed to stay on for extended period of times.

Comment: there are many ways to keep android's screen awake. But I'd like to find a device that doesn't have a battery, so I don't have to think when to charge it and so on. I'm ok with a stationary device that is always plugged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use any single-board minicomputer, for example, RaspberryPI, with an LCD screen
2. Use the tablet with the battery removed. The circuit diagram depends on the tablet model and the type of battery. In most cases this works.

Comment: Yes, I was considering the RaspberryPI approach. But was not sure if configuring it to work with an LCD screen would be easy enough. Also I asked in the Logitech Squeezebox forum, what other Logitech media server users use for this purpose, and came to a conclusion, that buying a used O2 Joggler (basically a tablet without a battery, which was released in 2009), would be the simplest way. So I have already bought one on ebay, and am waiting for it to arrive. It also has a 7" screen and came up cheaper than RaspberryPi with ~4" screen. So I'm looking forward to it.

Comment: Here are the links to the forum topic, I mentioned, and the Joggler wikipedia page, if anyone's interested: https://forums.slimdevices.com/showthread.php?98387-Dedicated-controller https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O2_Joggler

Comment: And about the tablets, which work without a battery - do you have any examples? I was considering using an old android phone and searched a bit if it's possible, but got the impression, that most android phones do not work without a battery, or some additional circuitry is needed to make the device think, that the battery is still there.

Comment: You won’t guess here. Different models work differently. It depends on which battery (2x, 3x or 4-wire), how the charge controller is arranged. In English - quite a few links (example - https://www.instructables.com/id/Power-an-Android-Phone-Without-Battery). You can find them yourself. In Russian - there is a big topic on 4pda - https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=653649. It will be possible to deal with the google translate, if it is not clear - I will help.

Comment: Honestly, I think you hurried to buy a specific model. At first, I would try to comprehensively study all aspects of this task. Honestly, I think you hurried to buy a specific model. At first, I would try to comprehensively study all aspects of this task. Yes, and also, it is advisable to buy a tablet with a battery, even if it is completely dead.

Comment: Ah yes, I believe there are a lot of information about this kind of DIY stuff in russian language. Too bad I don't understand russian. As for the instructables.com example, I have seen it, but this requires soldering and a part of a battery, and for the spare old android phone that I have, I already threw away the battery.

Comment: If you want to do it, sort it out. Walk and ye shall reach. I also don’t know French at all, and English is not my native language. And Chinese, in general, is a nightmare. So what?

1. To translate Russian and other languages, there is Google-translate (which is completely incomprehensible - you can ask).

2. Found another topic, different devices successfully modify. https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=4998

Comment: 3. Specifically for devices:
- Telcast
https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=653649&view=findpost&p=79547807
- PIPO M9Pro
https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=653649&view=findpost&p=79805876
- Samsung i9300 (Galaxy S3)
https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=653649&view=findpost&p=86013850
diode on battery controller
https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=499874&view=findpost&p=81734766
- Cube U55GT
https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=499874&view=findpost&p=68177418
https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=499874&view=findpost&p=68237824

Comment: These devices have earned

Comment: "Need soldering." What do you want? To click your fingers and it all worked? This does not happen. If you have a non-standard problem, and you have to solve it non-standard. Also inside the android, you may have to climb.

Comment: https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=499874

Comment: cool, thank you for all the links. I will keep them for future reference, you could also edit your answer to include some of the examples, if you want - for other people who see this question to find the solutions quicker.

Comment: you are welcome. If something is not clear in Russian - I will try to explain